# Keyboard layout switching doesn't work properly in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a great problem with switching keyboard layout from russian to english when working in Android Studio on Windows 7.
Soon after launching Studio switching back to english stops working and all letters I print are printed in russian, though all is OK with other applications.  Just restarting the Studio helps for a while. Keyboard switching is done by Alt+Shift or Ctrl+Shift, no matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same error, try to switch layout by <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and try <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> again.

This bug from 2011: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6290

Comment: the link seems about right, though I'm not working with android now and can't give it a try